# how to hide the background of the gif image when it is not being displayed?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a simple contact form 7 with little look change via css. the code of the form is as below:

```
<form action="/medical/#wpcf7-f13-o1" method="post" id="index-appointment-form" class="wpcf7-form col-md-7 col-lg-6 invalid" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="13">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.8.1">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f13-o1">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="d4ff0cd447">
    </div>

    /*here are codes for input elements*/

    //and below is the code for submit button and gif image and validation status 

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Make an appointment now" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-block btn-default">
        <img class="ajax-loader" src="http://localhost/medical/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;">
    </p>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-validation-errors" style="display: block;" role="alert">
        Validation errors occurred. Please confirm the fields and submit it again.
    </div>
</form>
```

workflow is if i click submit button gif image is shown at the buttom of the submit button(with the appearence of width and height attributes of 16px, 16px in img tag) , until the validation status message shows up. When status message shows up gif image disappears.

The problem is even there is no gif image being shown the background is always there before the click event and after the click event , and so there is always an unwanted empty gap below the submit button.

I tried using `.ajax-loader{display:none;}` , but then both the background and image are not showing up when i click the button. Even i tried `.show()` in jquery , nothing is showing up.

Basically i want there is no unwanted gap created by gif loader image when there is no image. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you share your js code also?

Comment: I think one your issue might be due to inline style of image "visibility:hidden"

Comment: yes there is visibility: hiden style attached to the gif. Basically contact form 7 is a plugin for wordpress and i'm trying to overright their style and js which comes by default. In this case how do i overright it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"visibility:hidden" will hide the element but the element's block will still be visible because there's a width and a height.
The jQuery "show()" function works with the CSS "display" property, not the "visibility" property.

**This jQuery code will solve your problem:**

```
$(".ajax-loader").css("visibility", "visible");
```

**The best solution would be to rely on the "display" property *only* :**

CSS:

```
.ajax-loader {display:none; visibility:visible;}
```

JS:

```
$(".ajax-loader").show();
```

You need to add the JS code when the user clicks on the button.

In another hand, the "visibility" CSS property isn't really useful in your case. You can get rid of it if you want.

Comment: i had to attach !important into visibility:visible to make it work.

Comment: but having problem when hiding it. i want to hide it when validation status is showing up(it is showing up using display:block). i'm using $('.wpcf7-submit').click(function(){
  $('.ajax-loader').show();
   if('block' ==  $('div.wpcf7-display-none').css('display')){
       $('.ajax-loader').show();
   }
}); but is not working , cause $('div.wpcf7-display-none').css('display') is outputting 'none' , i want to hide ajax-loader after wpcf7-display-none's style becomes block

Comment: To hide the element you can use:
$(".ajax-loader").hide();
If you're relying on the "visibility" property, then you can use:
$(".ajax-loader").css("visibility","hidden");
Again I would recommend the use of "display" instead of "visibility".

Comment: I tried that , it is not working. I made another post for that issue. please take a look at this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792159/how-to-show-an-element-do-something-else-and-then-hide-that-element-in-one-clic?noredirect=1#comment36595867_23792159)

Answer (score 1):

On the ajax-loader element, change the style from `visibility: hidden` to `display: none`. In order to show the element, set the style to `display: block`.

If `visibility: hidden` is set elsewhere, just set it to `visibility: visible` for the current element.

Make sure that when you hide the spinner, you use `display: none` (which should be the default for `$(".ajax-loader").hide()`.