# how to show an element, do something else and then hide that element in one click event?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using contact form 7. I have a form submit button, when i click it gif loader image shows up and then validation status message shows up along with gif image disappear.

in css i'm using `.ajax-loader{display:none;}`

in js i'm using

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').click(function(){
  $('.ajax-loader').show();

if('block' ==  $('div.wpcf7-display-none').css('display')){
         $('.ajax-loader').hide();
   }  
});
```

But this code is not working as alerting  `$('div.wpcf7-display-none').css('display')`
is still showing "`none`", instead of "`block`". Basically i'm trying to overwrite a plugin's code , instead of modifying them directly.

How do i hide back the gif image?

here is the form markup

```
<form>
//markup for different fields

//and here are the three main elements after clicking the submit button

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Make an appointment now" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-block btn-default">
<img class="ajax-loader" src="http://localhost/medical/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="display: inline-block; visibility: hidden;">
</p>

<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-validation-errors" style="display: block;" role="alert">
Validation errors occurred. Please confirm the fields and submit it again.
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's because you have a conditional statement that is saying if the element is set to `display:block` then change it to `display:none` basically, the way you have this coded currently, the element can never have `display:block` because, if it does, it will just revert back to `display:none`.

Comment: if you make the validation on the fly why you need to show the ajax loader? Usually show ajax loader when you send somewhere your form data, and then if the submit have success hide ajax loader.

Comment: @keypaul i'm trying to show the ajax loader for both client side validation and server side validation, suppose client didn't fill a field then ajax loader will show up then validation error message that please fill all fields , and also ajax loader disppear at the same time

Comment: Show ajax loader and then $.animate or $.fadeIn with a little duration. If you do with $.show and $.hide, as in your code, you don't see the effect (is instantaneous) Here a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/97jgJ/1/ but for a better solution you need to give us more detail, and better if you can make a fiddle of your code

Comment: delay will not serve the purpose of the ajax loader, ajax loader is waiting signal , not just for showing up. ajax loader has to stay until validation message is not showing up

Comment: Waiting signal of who? Validation message is on markup or you call/create it in other way? Cause if it is your markup (just display:none) there's no meaning to show an ajax loader (if there is not an ajax call). Or is just a fake animation to interact with the user?

Comment: when i click the submit button the div element of validation status shows up. in between the click and validation status shows up i want gif image will be shown and only for that time.i have edited the question by adding the markup.

Comment: Is strange show that ajax loader for that short time... http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/97jgJ/13/

Comment: @keypaul the fadeIn of validation div is being done somewhere else by the plugin's js . i'm just trying to overwrite it. the style="display:block" is being thrown in the div element via js somewhere else where i don't have access to. so i have to overwrite it and have to use something like when style="display:none" then hide the ajax loader. The code you have shown in jsfiddle is not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the functions in the callbacks of the previous function -

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').click(function(){
  $('.ajax-loader').show(function() {
      if('block' ==  $('div.wpcf7-display-none').css('display')){
         $('.ajax-loader').hide();
      }
  });  
});
```

Of course this is just speculation as we haven't seen your markup. What changes the display of `div.wpcf7-display-none`?

Comment: that is not working. div.wpcf7-display-none's style attribute is set to display:none, and being set to display:block when click event is happening via js

Comment: So `div.wpcf7-display-none` display status is being set when `.wpcf7-submit` is clicked? I'm not sure I follow because we don't have the markup and it seems that you're not fully describing what occurs.

Comment: yes div.wpcf7-display-none display status is being set(which is display:block) as well as gif image is being shown when .wpcf7-submit is clicked. i want gif image to be disappeared after div.wpcf7-display-none shows up.

Comment: Maybe the CSS class ("wpcf7-display-none") is assigned to hidden elements _only_. You might need to try this:
`if('block' ==  $('div.wpcf7-display-block').css('display')){
         $('.ajax-loader').hide();
}`. Just sayin'